# Button js doesn't work on mobile but works on desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, html

The below button works on desktop browsers but doesn't on mobile browsers. I tried the `touchend` and `touchstart` inside the `$(".theme-switch").on("click", () => {` but even they didn't seem to work when on mobile while perfectly working on desktop browsers. The purpose of the button is to change the site theme.

**html**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="header"><a class="theme-switch" href="#">Site</a></h1>
    </header>
</body>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let darkTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark';
    updateTheme();

    window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
        darkTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark';
        updateTheme();
    });

    function updateTheme() {
        if (darkTheme) {
            $("body").addClass("dark-theme");
        } else {
            $("body").removeClass("dark-theme");
        }
    }

    $(".theme-switch").on("click", () => {
        darkTheme = !darkTheme;
        updateTheme();
        localStorage.setItem('theme', darkTheme ? 'dark' : 'light');
    });
});
```

Comment: Working fine on Android / Chrome in my tests (the class 'dark-theme' is added and removed from the body when the link is touched). What devices do you find it doesn't work on?

Comment: Huh, I tested it on Android / Firefox.

Comment: Odd, OK for me on Android / FF too, class is added/removed. Sorry don't know where to go with this one...

Comment: Could you try, https://thelonelylands.com/simple which is the site I tried to implement this and failed to work on mobile. The theme should change when the landing page SIMPLE is pressed

Comment: OK so that doesn't work on either desktop or mobile for me because you're forcing the page to https but trying to load the jquery library over http so the browser blocks it: "Blocked loading mixed active content" resulting in no Jquery (ReferenceError: $ is not defined). Change http:// to https:// where you load jquery and try again.

Comment: Alright, that worked. So it was that blocking of the Http all this time. Thank you very much tho. I've been stuck with this for some time now.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Developer console is your friend for debugging, it revealed the error messages.

Comment: But the problem is, on my Win // FF it didn't show an error in the console. That's what baffled me at first. But it did to you. May I ask how or on what platform you debugged.

Comment: Initially I took the exact code posted in question to my local server and added an alert to the click handler so I could tell on both mobile and desktop that the click/touch was working. With the real site URL you added in the comments I just tested on current FF (75.0) on Windows and saw it didn't work and that the console revealed the http/https issue. Sounds like I was lucky that my desktop browser did reveal the problem. If it hadn't I'd have been using remote console for Chrome/Android to debug the mobile: https://dev.to/dev0x0/using-google-chrome-console-on-any-mobile-device-9ec